# Compile and run ansi standard sql queries

Tags: sql, subquery

I have several sql queries written in ansi standard sql 2008 that I copied from database textbook. I would like to compile and run them. How can this task be achieved? I tried to run them in SSMS but I got many syntax errors. Thanks:)

Comment: Well, at first you need to rid of the syntax errors. Can you show your SQL code?

Comment: We need more information: the query, the target database, the syntax error raised. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The syntax errors are due to the ANSI SQL keywords that don't exist in SSMS. Example: writing a recursive query in SSMS is different from writing a recursive query in ANSI SQL. How do I compile ANSI SQL code?

Comment: what application should I use to compile ANSI SQL code and get the results?

Comment: The ANSI Standards are just that. Standards. Think "guidelines". Different dialects of SQL adhere to the standards in different degrees, and their individual syntax for the standards they do support can vary, sometimes wildly. There will likely be some tweaking to be done no matter which database product you choose to work with.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a way to validate the ANSI SQL code?